# Modify reassign task form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

Can't figure it out, how do I open reassign task form in InfoPath?

I need it to modify that it would be fit for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where it is. You have to open you desired form then go to Page Design > View:

Click on view drop down list and you can see reassigntask form

[image]